# Transferring input from JFrame to another application(Non Java)

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm trying to create a virtual numpad in Java. The objective is to click a button (0...9) and input is reciprocated in another application with highlighted text field like notepad or calculator. In order to do that I used the robot class but it doesn't work. My code goes like this (for button click 0):

```
if(e.getSource()==b0){
        java.awt.Robot r = new java.awt.Robot();
        gui.setFocusable(false);
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_0);  
        gui.setFocusable(true);
}
```

I've tried to make the `JFrame` out of focus on button click so that input goes to highlighted application. Is there any way I can always keep my application on top without giving it focus?

Answer (score 0):

In order to show your frame on top always use:

```
Jframe.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
```

see more [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setAlwaysOnTop%28boolean%29%22%3EWindow.setAlwaysOnTop%28boolean%29)